# $\mathrm{Frac}(R)/R$ as a direct limit

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

Let $R$ be an integral domain, let $F=\mathrm{Frac}(R)$ be its field of fractions. Then $R$ is a submodule of $F$, hence we have quotient module $F/R$.

It is true that
$$F/R \cong \varinjlim R/rR$$ 
where the direct set is the set of nonzero element $r\in R$, and the partial order is given by
$$ r_{1} \preceq r_{2} \Leftrightarrow r_{1}\mid r_{2}$$

Can anyone explain to me that why it is true or not? Thank you very much.

Comment: How is $R$ an ideal of $F$ ?

Comment: You're  wrong: $R$ is not an ideal of $F$. A field has only two ideals: $(0)$ and itself.

Comment: You guys are right, I made a mistake in here.

Answer (score 1):

What is actually true is that $F$ is the limit of the direct system $(R_r, u_{rs})$, where each $R_r$ is copy of the ring $R$ and $u_{rs}\colon R_r\longrightarrow R_s$ is defined as multiplication by $r$ in $R$ whenever $r\mid s$.

Comment: Can you explain to me why this is true? Thanks

Comment: Oh, I figured it out. The canonical map from each $R_{r}$ to $F$ is given by $1\mapsto \frac{1}{r}$. This is indeed universal, cause the map from each $R_{r}$ to $F$ is completely determined by the map from $R_{1}$ to $F$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $R$ be an integral domain and $K$ be its fraction field.

Note that: (1). $K=\varinjlim_r R_r$ and (2). $R_r/R = \varinjlim_n R/r^n$.

Then $K/R = \varinjlim_r R_r/R = \varinjlim_r R/r$.